# Why won't this code delete rows from table?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
Using dbContext As pbu_housingEntities = New pbu_housingEntities
        ' First, delete all current records associated with the specified semester.
        Dim delete_old = (From p In dbContext.Residents _
                          Where p.semester = txtDestSemester.Text _
                          Where p.year = txtDestYear.Text _
                          Select p)
        dbContext.Residents.DeleteObject(delete_old)
        dbContext.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

But it doesn't work. It throws an unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery' error. Any thoughts?

All I'm trying to do is grab a list of rows with specified conditions and then delete all the rows returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `delete_old` could be more than 1 item.

Add a `ToList()` and iterate over each entry and call the `DeleteObject` method for each enumerated item.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: `delete_old` will always be an IEnumerable, even if it only finds one record.